# Scala future to Java Completable future

Tags: java, scala, future, completable-future

1 - is there any lib or recommendation on our to go from Scala future to Java Completable future ?

I have a legacy system that I need to adapt to a Scala lib that returns futures in its API.

2 - Also I was wondering how the intricacy between threadPool executor works. By intricacy I mean, the fact that from the legacy Java app I would be working on the forkjoin common Pool and that Scala lib has his own ThreadPool executors.

This last question is something I always wonder, how the communication between thread poolexecutor happens. In Java you can somewhat poll, cancel future, so would you do that from another context.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this lib: https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/test/java/scala/compat/java8/FutureConvertersTest.java

I think it can help you.